# java.lang.RuntimeException com.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule.onActivityResult

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-picker

My app crashes while using `react-native-image-picker` library in my android app. I am using `react-native-image-picker` library to select image from the gallery and capture a photo from the camera. I am not able to find any solution regarding this crash. any solution?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:4662)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:4704)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute (ActivityResultItem.java:49)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:113)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:71)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2036)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7081)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:928)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CallbackImpl.invoke (Unknown Source:23)
  at com.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule.onActivityResult (Unknown Source:35)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.onActivityResult (Unknown Source:18)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult (ReactInstanceManager.java:6)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.onActivityResult (ReactDelegate.java:22)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onActivityResult (ReactActivityDelegate.java:3)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onActivityResult (ReactActivity.java:2)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:7588)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:4655)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:4704)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute (ActivityResultItem.java:49)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:113)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:71)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2036)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7081)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:928)
```